# How to escape the single quotes and double quotes at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this :

```
<div onclick="location.href='RandomURL.com/index'></div>
```

I want to append this div to another div that got the ID : divId :

```
$("#divId").html('<div onclick="location.href= ??
```

As you can see I want to put the character ( " ) **after href**= , but I already used one with **onclick=**

I can not use as well the character ( ' ) , because I already used one with **$("#divId").html(**

How to escape this scenario ? (without having to create another javascript function if possible)

Comment: Why do you need `onclick`? However `$("#divId").html('<i onclick="location.href=\'RandomURL.com/index\'"></i>')`

Comment: because I want the div to be clickable

Comment: _“How to escape this scenario ?”_ – same way escaping always works in JavaScript - by prepending the offending character with a backslash.

Comment: you can escpate it with a backslash and use the single quote again like `\'http..\'`

Comment: Try using unobtrusive event handlers instead of outdated `on*` event attributes. You won't have this issue at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a backslash character (`\`) to escape it:

```
$("#divId").html('<div onclick="location.href=\"xxx\""');
```

Here are [characters](http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html) that need to be escaped in javascript strings:

- Horizontal Tab: `\t`
- Vertical Tab:  `\v`
- Nul char:  `\0`
- Backspace: `\b`
- Form feed: `\f`
- Newline: `\n`
- Carriage return:  `\r`
- Single quote:  `\'`
- Double quote:  `\"`
- Backslash: `\\`

As stated in the comments, I would do something different in this case:

```
$('#divId').html('<div id="foo">');
$('#foo').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'xxx';
});
```

Comment: I do not know what to prefer... mixing single quotes with doubles... or use only doubles, or only singles. Tends to get unreadable fast.

Comment: @CasparKleijne, definitely :) In OP's specific case I would choose a different solution, such as an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try using backslash to escape single and double quotes.

```
$("#divId").html('<div onclick="location.href=\'RandomURL.com/index\'"></div>');
```

It is better to use event delegation.

```
$('#divId').html('<div id="foo">');

$(document).on('click', '#foo', function() {
    window.location.href = 'RandomURL.com/index';
});
```

Comment: Why is it better?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest quotes up to four times:

```
" > \" > ' > \'
```

or

```
' > \' > " > \"
```

In your case it would be sth. like

```
$("#divId").html("<div onclick=\"location.href='RandomURL.com/index';\"></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6 [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Use the `` symbols to enclose your html code. In your case it would be:

```
$("#divId").html(`<div onclick="location.href= ??"></div>`);
```

You can include as many quotes [ ' ], double quoutes [ " ], and backslashes [ \ ] as you please inside the string.